# Deadlock with threads calling down on kernel semaphore through sysfs

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Originating from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17391276/912144) (and [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443774/912144)), I have come to realize there is a possible deadlock, but I can't understand why and how I can avoid it.

In short, there is a `semaphore` in kernel space that kernel modules (they are really applications running in kernel space) could take, but user space applications would also need to take the same semaphore for protecting a globally shared memory.

I have done this by exposing a sysfs file which given the correct character, would `down` or `up` the semaphore in kernel space. The user space applications would just keep this file open and `write` the appropriate character for the lock to take place.

Here's a sample kernel module for demonstration:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/semaphore.h>
#include <linux/sysfs.h>
#include <linux/kobject.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Shahbaz Youssefi");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Test module");

static struct kobject *_kobj = NULL;
static struct semaphore sem;

static ssize_t _lock_op(struct kobject *kobj, struct kobj_attribute *attr, const char *buf, size_t count)
{
    switch (buf[0])
    {
    case '0':
        printk("down (%u)\n", sem.count);
        if (down_interruptible(&sem))
            printk("error: sem wait interrupted\n");
        break;
    case '1':
        printk("up (%u)\n", sem.count);
        up(&sem);
        break;
    default:
        printk("error: invalid request %d\n", buf[0]);
    }
    return count;
}

static struct kobj_attribute _lock_attr = __ATTR(test, 0222, NULL, _lock_op);

static int __init _main_init(void)
{
    sema_init(&sem, 1);

    _kobj = kobject_create_and_add("test", NULL);
    if (!_kobj)
    {
        printk("error: failed to create /sys directory for test\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    if (sysfs_create_file(_kobj, &_lock_attr.attr))
        printk("error: could not create /sys file\n");

    printk("loaded\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit _main_exit(void)
{
    if (_kobj)
        kobject_put(_kobj);
    _kobj = NULL;

    printk("unloaded\n");
}

module_init(_main_init);
module_exit(_main_exit);
```

This works great in general.  The user-space applications can write `'0'` or `'1'` to the sysfs file and they achieve mutual exclusion without a problem.

However, there is one case where this locks up the process, and that is when multiple threads of the same process try to acquire the lock.

Essentially, something like this:

```
       Thread 1               Thread 2

       write '0'
      system call
       _lock_op
   down_interruptible
   return from syscall
                              write '0'
                             system call
                              _lock_op
                           down_interruptible (blocked)

*go on to release the lock*

                            *return from syscall*
                         *go on to release the lock*
```

The problem is that in such a case, where the second `down` happens while the first one still hasn't released the lock, instead of just the second thread getting blocked, **the whole process gets blocked**. That is, the steps marked with `*` don't happen.

Here's a user-space application that can trigger this when the above kernel module is inserted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

static int fid;
static volatile sig_atomic_t interrupted = 0;

static void sig_handler(int signum)
{
    interrupted = 1;
}

static void *func(void *arg)
{
    while (!interrupted)
    {
        write(fid, "0", 1);
        write(fid, "1", 1);
        usleep(1000);
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t tid;

    struct sigaction sa = {
        .sa_handler = sig_handler,
    };
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGHUP, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGQUIT, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL);
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &sa, NULL);

    fid = open("/sys/test/test", O_WRONLY);
    if (fid < 0)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, func, NULL);

    while (!interrupted)
    {
        write(fid, "0", 1);
        write(fid, "1", 1);
        usleep(793);
    }

    pthread_join(tid, NULL);

    close(fid);

    return 0;
}
```

Note: do `echo 1 > /sys/test/test` to unblock yourself ;)

**My question is, why does Linux block the whole process on `down` rather than just the calling thread?** And what can I do about it?

---

Note: tested on x86, kernel 3.8 patched with RTAI. I will try with a newer an vanilla kernel later just to be sure, but I suspect it is unrelated to RTAI.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually figured out a way to go around this problem, but I still think there should be a proper explanation and a solution.

My workaround is the following:

Take a pthread mutex in the application. On each thread, instead of:

```
write(fid, "0", 1);
/* access */
write(fid, "1", 1);
```

do

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
write(fid, "0", 1);
/* access */
write(fid, "1", 1);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
```

This makes all accesses by the process to the sysfs file mutually exclusive. The sysfs file makes sure the accesses are mutually exclusive among processes and kernel modules.