# When and how do we lock to prevent conflicts between shared memory?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, locking

Let's say we have a process that memory mapped another process' memory area, but the process that holds the original memory area, is writing to an address in the shared memory area. How do we avoid conflicts between the memory areas when doing I/O operations?

I share memory page between my kernel module and a user-space process of mine, and I came across [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=memory-understanding-mapping) article that explains memory mapping deeply, and according to IBM, we must ensure that:

> Processes using shared memory areas must set up a signal or semaphore
> control method to prevent access conflicts and to keep one process
> from changing data that another is using.

I have a `memcpy` that copies memory into a `kmap`ped virtual kernel address of a user space page. Right now it works great, but I'm worried that if the user-space process the page is associated to, is writing to the exact address my `memcpy` is. How do I keep the above rule? `mmap_write_lock` with my `mm_struct` doesn't work, it deadlocks.

```
kvaddr = kmap(p);

mmap_write_lock(mm); /* ERR: Deadlock */
memcpy(kvaddr, src, strlen(src));
mmap_write_unlock(mm);
```

Comment: I guess the deadlock is because the task is already holding the lock (depending where this code is called from). But code in userspace won't be using this lock anyway.

Comment: @IanAbbott - Thank you for your comment. I tested it for a while with a process that writes to the same memory, and a process that doesn't, and the results are the same, it still deadlocks. _code in userspace won't be using this lock anyway._ - Does it mean there's no need to hold a lock? I don't perform any other writing in my kernel space.

Comment: `mmap_write_lock` is about locking the `mm_struct` object for prevents changing of the **mapping**, not the **content** of the memory. The article you cite is about **cooperative** synchronization between the processes, when one process **expects** the other will use the same memory. Since a user space process is definitely not aware about your kernel mapping, the only way to prevent the user process from accessing the memory is preventing its scheduling. Not sure whether it is possible, but such manual intervention into scheduling is definitely discouraged by the Linux kernel.

Comment: You cannot possibly use locking like this to prevent any conflict (apart from the fact that as @Tsyvarev mentions, locking the `mm_struct` does not do what you think). Locking requires cooperation between the parties. If you are only locking stuff in kernel space, user space is still allowed to do whatever it wants. You need the two to somehow communicate and agree on the order of operations. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/17391276/3889449.